# Stored procedure called parellel returning results sequentially

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

We wrote stored procedures in MYSQL

If the stored procedure is called from one thread its taking 2.5 seconds to return results

If the stored procedure is called from 3 thread its taking approx 8.5 seconds to return results . each thread is taking almost the same time.

We are using MyISM, please let me know if we need to do any settings for the procedure to be executed parellely. We are only retrieving(selects) in the stored procedure no updates/insertion done

Comment: even simultaneous requests are context/process switched. So is pulling data from DB. that 1 second more is the overhead of context switching.

Comment: Use more threads when MySQL is idle and all existing threads  are busy processing some data they pulled from MySQL.

Comment: its taking 8.5 secs for each thread when 3 thread are executed. -> total 8.5 *  3

Comment: You mean it takes 25.5 secs with threads and just 7.5 secs with sequential calls? That's worse..!

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the number of threads to pull data from MySQL not necessarily increase throughput. You're executing the same query in multiple threads which adds to overhead of context switching.

To take advantage of threading you need to make use of idle time(the real idle time), like input/output/network delays.
Example:

- A thread pulls some data from MySQL and starts processing, say sending notification over an interface. If that interface is synchronous then thread is stuck.
- Get more threads to do the job for you, i.e pull data from DB(Idle) and process.

without such delays/idling threading only incurs overhead IMO.